# What is an inner page?

Tags: html

And can you provide some examples?

From my understanding, an inner page is the page with the content, like the content div in the html, am i wrong?

Comment: What are your references? This is completely arbitrary.

Comment: Voting to close as 'not a real question.' @dave, if you can rephrase your question, with context and reference, then please let me know with an `@`-name prefixed comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say without context, but it could refer to a page loaded inside a frame or to a page that is not the homepage for a website.